# Transfer of the site, with change of the database (MySQL to MariaDB)

Tags: database, joomla-4.x

I built my website with Joomla4 and a MySQL8.0 database. Unfortunately, I need to transfer my site to a server using MariaDB10.4, which isn't compatible with MySQL8.0.

I'm not a programmer and changing manually the code in the current database to fit with MariaDB language would be too hard for me, so I'm thinking of re-building my website on the new server. I will keep exactly the same website; the only change concerns the MariaDB database.

I'm looking for software to make this process easier, e. g.: not having to re-create all articles, categories, associations and modules in the new Joomla4 installation.

I don't have several users so a transfer of users isn't important

I saw that there is a software called SP transfer -- which seems interesting. I read the descriptions of this software and tried to understand as well as I can, but am not entirely sure that it can do what I need (transferring as much as possible from the old site, but not the MySQL database, and without having to manually work on the database).

Do you think SP tranfer could do what I need? I'm not a computer scientist so I'm not sure when only reading the descriptions of the product. As SP transfer is a paid download, I would like to check if it really fits my situation before buying it.

If you have recommendations for other software, don't hesitate to let me know. (Other software that I saw were for Joomla3, not Joomla4).

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour] while you wait for support/feedback.

Comment: I don't think you would need to make any code changes to keep the same site that you have now. A quick google shows other entries on JSE, non-Joomla related, that suggest you can use mysqldump to backup the MySql 8.0 db and restore it to the Maria 10 environment which could be an option. Also reading Akeeba Backup pages it suggest it might be possible to back up your MySQL site using Akeeba  and restore the site using Akeeba on your server using Maria. Either option, if they work, would be easier than Building a new site and migrating data.

Comment: Thank you Irata for your help. As I've understood until now, mysqldump and Akeeba cannot "rewrite"/"translate" my MySQL files into MariaDB language. And MySQL8.x isn't compatible with MariaDB10.x.
I have other websites with MySQL5.x and tranfered them using Akeeba/Quickstart, and they work fine on the MariaDB server, but that is because MySQL5.x is compatible with MariaDB, which isn't the case anymore with MySQL8.x.